# Can't use recovery to reset my Mac password

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, password

Help, I'm currently having a problem with recovery. The PC won't accept my password (it's actually correct but for some reason, the PC wouldn't accept it so I decided to use recovery to change the password). When I got to the recovery menu and the utilities page..
At the prompt, while trying to type 'resetpassword' I clicked the letter R on the keyboard, the code (-bash-3.2) changed to (arg 0) and then non of the letters I type show on the prompt and I can't proceed to reset the password. I've been stuck with this for a while now

Comment: Do you have a FileVault Encryption enable on you rmacbook pro?

Comment: No I don't have it enabled

Comment: I often overlook that a wrong keyboard layout is selected. Are you sure you are using the right keyboard layout?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, how do I know if the keyboard layout is wrong and if it's wrong, how do I change it?

Comment: The keyboard may also be physically failing — have stuck keys, be sending wrong key codes, something like that.